# Landlord's LLC filed for bankruptcy, is that a breach of contract?

Tags: residential-lease, bankruptcy, breach-of-contract

My landlord owns and maintains the property I'm leasing though an LLC. The lease documents are between myself and the LLC.

I was recently sent a letter that says that my landlord's LLC is filing for bankruptcy. He mentioned that future rent checks should be made out in his name  rather than to the LLC like it was previously.

Does this mean he is breaching the lease agreement? Would I be within my rights to break the agreement because of this?

Comment: I wouldn't change how rent is paid unless you hear it from the property owner (the LLC).  The Landlord's say-so is not good enough if he personally isn't either the owner or listed on the lease.

Comment: This is an interesting accounting question. It could be that the landlord is diverting assets (your rent payments) from the LLC that is filing for bankruptcy, and that may be a legal issue, but I'd suspect that it would be separate from your ability to break the lease.

Comment: I'd investigate if you paid any deposits to the LLC, and what are the consequences if the LLC goes bankrupt.

Comment: @gnasher729 I was actually listed as a "Creditor" in his bankruptcy forms, which I found unusual, although it makes sense if he has my security deposit.  This guy seems like he is "Scamming" the system and I'm afraid he will try to steal my deposit.

Comment: @BenVoigt if the landlord is a member, manager, or agent of the LLC, which I suppose he probably is, how would Cheesus Crust be expected to understand that an instruction from the landlord is *not* coming "from the property owner (the LLC)"?

Comment: @phoog: It still has to be issued formally in his capacity as officer of the LLC, and with bankruptcy proceedings ongoing, it may be that the LLC's officers no longer have the authority to issue such instructions and must get approval from the court / bankruptcy trustee.  So no, instructions personally from the landlord are not to be understood as coming from the property owner.

Comment: Upon the filing of the bankruptcy, the LLC no longer owns any of its property (unless it is a U.S. Chapter 11), it is instead the property of a bankruptcy estate. In this case, the landlord is probably committing a crime and should probably be reported to bankruptcy officials or the police.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'll double check the documents when I get home, but what would Chapter 11 entail?  I don't feel comfortable being a part of my Landlords potentially illegal activity.  I would like to know details before I make any calls, hah.

Comment: In a Chapter 11 the company is run by existing management as "debtor-in-possession" but still isn't allowed to divert funds from the BK estate. You should have gotten some official notice of the BK filing in the mail.

Comment: @ohwilleke I did get the notice, of which I was listed as a creditor.  Who could I contact about the bankruptcy without asking my landlord?  (Since being a listed creditor on a document I was not involved with concerns me)

Comment: @CheesusCrust The letter would identify a court case name and number and the address of the court clerk whom you could contact.

Comment: @ohwilleke Awesome, thanks for all your help.  I will look into my options (If any) regarding removing myself from this lease.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your lease is with the LLC in bankruptcy - you should not be paying rent to anyone else. Unless and until the lease is transferred to someone else (in accordance with the terms of the lease or with your agreement) it will remain with the LLC. Contact the bankruptcy trustee to see how they intend to proceed.

Providing the LLC keeps fulfilling its obligations under the lease there is no breach.

Comment: I'll look into this, although, considering the landlord himself told me to start writing checks in his name rather than the LLC shows me he may be trying to hide money.

Comment: @CheesusCrust It appears that this is little more than blatant theft from the bankruptcy estate. I have a case where the manager of an LLC landlord who is a disbarred lawyer is trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 5):

The LLC **is** your landlord.

The person who owns the LLC may be doing any number of things, some of which have dubious legality.

However, none of them are related to your lease agreement, which is with an LLC, which is now under the management of an official assignee. Until such time as the actual landlord, the LLC under control of the official assignee, communicates a change in payment directions, you should continue to act as you have been, because the agreement is entirely unchanged and unaffected.

If the property is transferred as part of settling the debts, your lease remains intact. You simply have a new landlord with the exact same rights and responsibilities as before.

Comment: As someone that is trying to break free of this lease (To avoid issues with the shady business of the Landlord), would it be possible?

Comment: Presumably, the person identified by Cheesus Crust as the landlord has been the LLC's agent in all matters related to the property (for example, signing the lease).  How then is Cheesus Crust to understand that the instruction from that person to change the payee of his rent checks isn't being communicated to him by "the actual landlord, the LLC"?

Comment: If it is going under, it will have an official assignee, whose authority is now needed. If they don't have an authorisation from the assignee, they don't have agency. Since the issue is the original owner's management, the assignee is almost guaranteed not to involve them in acting on both sides of the bankruptcy (as the owner of the bankrupt company and as the agent of the assignee managing that bankruptcy). @phoog

Comment: See edits. Your lease continues through transfer (sale or otherwise) of the property. The new owner becomes your new landlord, under the exact same lease.

Comment: So it seems that, unfortunately, I may not be able to do anything except follow through with my agreement?  Even though my deposit may be at risk?

Comment: Your deposit should be perfectly safe - if your jurisdiction mandates placing it with a trusted third party such as an independent bond-holding agency. Otherwise, you may have the right to reclaim the bond from the landlord at the time of termination, regardless of who it is. A contract lawyer who is especially familiar with tenancy law would be necessary to work out whether that's going to be a successful argument, though.

Comment: @Nij In theory, you are right. In practice, embezzlement of security deposits probably takes place in at least half of situations like this and so the money may very well no longer be there.

Comment: I think in a situation like this, and given the tenant does not appear to have a surety from the bond-holding agency, since they wouldn't need to ask if they had it, the bond is likely being held by the LLC - and the owner is then likely to be "looking after it".